Spectral energy density of black body radiation

$u(\nu,T)$ is known as the amount of energy emitted per unit frequency $\nu$ per unit volume $V$. It is the function of $\nu$ and $T$. In case we would like to know the amount of energy density at specific frequency, for example at $4.0 \times 10^{14} \ \text{Hz}$, the calculation must be $$(4.0 \times 10^{14}) \times u(4.0 \times 10^{14}, T).$$ Am I right? Thank you.

The function $u(\nu, T)$ gives the energy density per unit range of frequency. Since, it doesn't make sense to compute the energy density for an exact frequency $\nu$, the function gives us the energy density for all frequencies in the range $\nu$ to $\nu+d\nu$, divided by the range $d\nu$. This range must be small, because the function itself varies with frequency.
For example, the energy density for frequencies between $4.0\times10^{14}$ Hz and $4.1\times10^{14}$ Hz will be:
$$u(4.0\times10^{14}, T) \times 0.1 \times 10^{14} \text{ Hz}$$
Here, we can use either $u(4.0\times10^{14}, T)$ or $u(4.1\times10^{14}, T)$, since their values are close to each other. However, keep note of the range. If the range was twice as big, say from $4.0\times10^{14}$ Hz to $4.2\times10^{14}$ Hz, then even though the value of $u(\nu, T)$ doesn't vary much, the computed energy density would roughly double. (You can see this intuitively too: roughly the same value at different frequencies, so the more the frequencies the more the total value).
For larger ranges, you'll have to integrate over different values of $u(\nu, T)$. But always remember, the energy density is the product of the function and the $range$ of frequency. Not just the frequency.
